# How to integrate new scripts to older versions when using Flyway

Tags: flyway

Let's say I have an app in version 1.

I submit 2 scripts to Flyway named:
V1__Add_users_table and
V2__Update_users_table

In version 2, I add a new script:
V3__Add_orders_table

And in version 3 of the app I submit a new script:
V4__Add_tests_table

Let's say I'm required to merge the feature that required the V4 script backwards to version 1 of the app.
If I add the V4 script to the scripts folder of my client that is still using version 1 of my app so that its flyway folder looks like this:

- V1__Add_users_table
- V2__Update_users_table
- V4__Add_tests_table

The next time I want to upgrade the client to version 3 of the app, Flyway will not run the V3 script, because as far as Flyway is concerned the last scripts it ran was V4.

Is there a way to push my V4 script to the client while in version 1 of the app as V2.1 script so that it will not bump the scripts version artificially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your assumption is wrong. Assuming you've set [outOfOrder=true](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/out-of-order-184127522.html), Flyway will run any pending (unrun) scripts when you next migrate, so the V3 script ***will run*** in your scenario above.

If you want to match released versions with migration script versions, then instead of adding the Add_tests_table as V4, you could add it as V1.1, and you could even choose to migrate up to V1.1 if you don't want to include any migration scripts beyond this version using the [-target parameter](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/target-184127546.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was not aware this was possible.
However, when using outOfOrder=true, it gives me a warning when I use this flag, is there any known issues with using it?

Comment: No product issues. It's just that in theory if you have migrations 1, 2 and 3, and you apply these in order, it's theoretically possible that if you apply them out of order, say 1, 3 and 2, that the end state isn't identical. And in some cases out of order migrations simply won't work because script 3 relies on 2 having been run first.

Comment: When I tried it, it did not look like it was running the scripts out of order. It did 1, 2, 3, etc. It was just not skipping older versions than the one it had ran as the last one